# How can I get mobile node IP address in OPNET 14.5?

Tags: opnet

I tried the following code in OPNET Modeler 14.5

```
Objid addr_info_attr_objid;
char address_string[128];
addr_info_attr_objid = op_id_self();
op_ima_obj_attr_get(addr_info_attr_objid, "Address", address_string);
```

to get the node IP Address but it gives this error message:

```
<<<Recoverable Error>>>
Attribute name(Address) is unrecognizzed for object(542)
```

Comment: Also, i tried to use op_ima_obj_attr_get_str ( Objid_node , "Address", IPC_OBJTYPE_MOB , node_address);

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the proper IP interface First. 
Based on your code, it is not right way to get IP address of one-interface node, such as Server/Client model.

Here is sample code

```
op_ima_obj_attr_get(ip_moudle_objid, "IP Router Parameters [0].Interface Information [3].Address", &address_str);
```